# Hexagonal chess AI in prolog

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am looking forward to write a "Shafrans hex chess AI in prolog" . Is there any already available open source code available for reference ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_chess (for info on Shafrans hexgonal chess)

Answer (score 2):

Games between 2 opponents can be tackled with [alpha/beta search](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/5_3.html). That's the most basic 'framework', and introduces the ingredients you will need when you'll improve your game.

You will at least implement [MinMax](http://ai.ia.agh.edu.pl/wiki/prolog%3apllib%3abest-move_minimax). Those two arguments are illustrated in `The Art Of Prolog` by Sterling & Shapiro

Answer (score 0):

There is a codeplex project - https://hexchess.codeplex.com/ for several hexagonal chess variants including, I think, Shafrans. The code is not in prolog, but code is code and this should give you a start if you are still looking.